# Strange CPU load on HP DL165 g7 with Windows 2008 R2 core enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008, hp, central-processing-unit, opteron

We decided to give a chance to a new opteron "Magny Cours" processor and instantly faced a problem with slow system response on Windows 2008 R2. BIOS and BMC firmwares are latest found on HP, no chipset drivers installed/needed, Adaptec RAID is used.

Anyone successfully run these type of servers?

[image]

Comment: You're not giving us anything to work on, what are you trying to do here, how's the memory loaded out - more details please, much more.

Comment: It's a fresh install, no applications are consuming CPU.

Comment: We're running the 12-core versions of these processors (in a BL465 G7) and haven't had any issues with them yet. Haven't done Server 2008r2 yet, but I HAVE done Windows 7 (there was a good reason) and ESX.

Comment: Have you setup the memory correctly? setting it up wrong can create just this kind of problem, also have you applied the latest Proliant Support Pack?

Comment: There is no PSP for 100-series. Memory installed according to manual(otherwise server will not start). Thanks guys, I resolved it. It was a intel (HAHAHA) integrated NIC, after I installed updated driver for it, cpu saw disappeared. Old version did not liked SP1 for some reason.

Comment: @Alex - please feel free to post your answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BenPilbrow He'll have to wait another 21 hours due to a new restriction on new users answering their own questions (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186).

Answer (score 1):

Check the integrated NIC drivers, they can cause problems.